# Looking for a story with "The Cutting Edge", a cutting instrument which that can cut anything and might be Death's Scythe

Tags: story-identification, books, urban-fantasy

It's set in the modern world.  It has a female protagonist, and I think she inherits "The Cutting Edge" from its former owner, probably a relative. I want to say via "grandfather's will", and she moves to a new town to deal with her duty?

I'm pretty sure that the cutting implement was "The Cutting Edge", because it stuck out to me, but I'm unsure what form it took.

I am more sure that she wants to be free of her inherited job as being Death, or negotiating between "monsters" and "humanity" or something, and it took place on what seems to be basically Modern Earth with computers and stuff, or at least the blurb and probably the cover didn't imply that it's *not* Earth. How the existence of monsters meshes with that, I'm unsure.

I only read the blurb for this book, somewhere in the 2000s.

I also don't think it's Grath Garham's Finder's Keepers, but if a copy of the blurb of a print copy could be found, possibly on https://search.worldcat.org/, I'd be able to confirm or deny.

The first 412 out of 973 Fiction books dug up from WorldCat [that are related to "cutting edge" from 1990 to 2015](https://search.worldcat.org/search?q=cutting+edge&content=fic&datePublished=1900-2015&inLanguage=eng&itemSubType=book-printbook%2Cbook-digital%2Cbook-mic%2Cbook-thsis%2Cbook-mss%2Cbook-largeprint&itemType=book&limit=10&offset=451) aren't ringing any bells.

<sub><sup>*Not *The Subtle Knife* by by Philip Pullman</sup></sub>

Comment: "saw it"? Is this a video presentation or a story?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - It's a book, but I never read the contents, just the back blurb.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Long shot as it doesn't match all the details, hence not making this an answer, but have you ruled out Susan from Terry Pratchett's Discworld series (appears in Soul Music, Hogfather, and Thief of Time)?

Comment: @justme - I'm sure it's not that, since I thought of her after typing up my latest changes mentioning a "grandfather" too! If it were a Discworld novel, I would've actually borrowed it and read it! None of the blurbs match either! Heh.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be the webcomic [Finder's Keepers](https://www.finderskeepers.gcgstudios.com/) by Garth Graham?

Female protagonist in urban fantasy has access to "*The Cutting Edge*", an absurdly sharp blade gifted to her by Death that can cut anything, including reality.

[image]

It was published in graphic novel format in the early 2000s.

Comment: Well, this sure is the first example of something that actually has a "The Cutting Edge", and obviously timeline would fit. If you could find a shot of the back of a printing that has the blurb in focus, I'd be able to confirm or deny.

Comment: @Malady - I've looked but copies of this seen to be vanishingly rare

Comment: I've seen a few on eBay and kept thinking that the Wrench Girl back cover was some weirdness, but if it's right and there's no Back Blurb, then this isn't it. - https://www.ebay.com/itm/133656095735

Comment: @Malady - The graphic novels will likely have a blurb

Comment: Well, if this - http://ka-blam.com/main/ka-blam-print-ads/ - Is accurate, then that eBay link might be real legit: "You can lower your printing costs by allowing us to purchase a full-page ad on the back cover of your comic (or the inside back cover of your paperback)."

Comment: @Malady - The original versions were sold in shops, as far as I can tell. That means no custom printing, an ISBN number (and bar-code) and a blurb. It was pretty common for a popular webcomic to get a print run back then, for comicbook stores and even main retail

Comment: Would you know which shops? The web archive has this personal shop - https://web.archive.org/web/20090216121112/http://www.gcgstudios.com/?p=store&s=misc